# rerouting after calling a function in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm getting my feet wet with Laravel 5 and I need a little advice on Routing.

I'm running in to a problem over and over and I feel like I'm definitely not grasping the proper way to do this.

Lets say I have a route:

```
Route::post('viewarticles', 'LoginController@user_check_article_list');
```

This is where I am taken after I login.
This route shows me my articles that I can edit.  On the page this route takes you to I have a list of articles and delete buttons next to them.  When I click delete I have it linked to

```
delete/{{ $article->id }}
```

I then have a route:

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', 'ArticleController@deleteArticle');
```

Which then goes to this function:

```
public function deleteArticle(Request $request, $id) {

        $article = Article::find($id);
        $article->delete();
        $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->Published()->get();
        return view('admin.article_edit_list',['articles'=>$articles]);

}
```

The last two lines of this is me rebuilding that article list and then loading the view.

THE PROBLEM:  In my url the page is still ../delete/someid

I really just need a way to transfer back to the routes.

Comment: you want to display article through user, why you need to display post method route, I mean why not method `get` than get the all the article through relations `one to many` Eloquent by user if user authenticated. Make Sense? @nibbcnoble

Comment: and than for delete article as you mention, first delete article and `deattach` as per the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a view, return a redirect.  This will cause the url to change:

```
public function deleteArticle(Request $request, $id) 
{
        $article = Article::find($id);
        $article->delete();
        return redirect('/some-url');
}
```

Or if using named routes:

```
return redirect()->route('some.route.name');
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

Comment: I also tried the named route method and that worked as well, for those interested: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes  Thanks @watcher

Answer (score 0):

so if your url is staying at /delete/{id} you need to redirect to the the display articles view

```
  public function deleteArticle(Request $request, $id) {

    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->delete();
    return \Redirect::to('show_articles.view');

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

how do you send the delete request ? is it via ajax?

if so you need to redirect to your view in the success method of your ajax call using js / most likely jQuery?

```
      .success(function(){
         location.href = '/your/new/view';
      });
```

its worth checking your variables are getting through to your controller as well

```
   public function ...
   echo $id; exit(); // or dd($id);
```

and checking your collection loaded 
        $articles = ...
        dd($artcles);
        retrun view(...

also if you go in to app/config/app.php and set debug=true you should get an error stack which will help debug the issue. Sorry for the delay internet went down before I could finish typing.

Comment: no I'm just routing to a function..  <a href="/delete/id">delete</a>

Comment: Take a look at my edit and let me know if that helps, my internet went before I could finish sorry.

Comment: This isn't really the problem I'm having...  I'm trying to get my url to reflect the page that I'm on.  I could do the ajax solution but I'm guessing there is an answer that is related to laravel routing.  There isn't really anything to debug...

Comment: I got you, you need to redirect to your articles view after delete see my second answer